# get point coordination using path.getPointAtLength after rotation in d3 and svg

Tags: d3.js, svg

i want get some points from path after rotating it

i use below code to rotate path

```
let path= svg.append("path")
.attr("class","offset control")
.attr("d", lineFunction(offsetLineData))

.style("stroke-width", 0.5)
.style("stroke", "red")
.style("fill", "none")
.attr("transform","rotate(90,"+p.x+","+p.y+")")
.attr('transform-origin',"center")
```

then i want get end point and start point of path

```
path.node().getPointAtLength(0)
```

but it return coordination where it don't rotated
how can i get x and y of point after rotation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of a SVG as a tree of nested coordinate systems. Every element has its own coordinates, and is fitted into its parent with a rule how to re-calculate them. These rules can be explicit `transform` attributes, but also implicit combinations of `width`, `height` and  `viewBox` ("fit box A in size B").

A `transform` attribute is considered to be the link to the parent element. That means, if you ask for a geometric property of an element, most of the times you get the value *before* the transform is applied. *After* it is applied would be asking for geometric values in the coordinate system of the parent.

Because of this complexity there are several SVG API functions to find out how these coordinate systems fit together. `getPointAtLength()` gets you coordinates *before* applying the `transform` attribute.

```
var localPoint = path.node().getPointAtLength(0)
```

First, you have to find out what the `transform` attribute does. This looks a bit complicated, partly because the attribute can be animated and can contain a list of functions, partly because the API is...well...:

```
// construct a neutral matrix
var localMatrix = path.node().viewportElement.createSVGMatrix()
var localTransformList = path.node().transform.baseVal
 // is there at least one entry?
if (localTransformList.length) {
    // consolidate multiple entries into one
    localMatrix = localTransformList.consolidate().matrix
}
```

You can then apply the found transformation to the point with

```
var transformedPoint = localPoint.matrixTransform(localMatrix)
```

There are several functions hat will return a [`SVGMatrix`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix) to transform data from the coordinate system *after* application of the `transform` attribute (i. e. after the step above):

- to ask for the transformation to the nearest viewport (in most cases the nearest parent `<svg>`) element: `element.getCTM()`
- to ask for the transformation to screen pixels:  `element.getScreenCTM()`
- to ask for the transformation to an arbitrary element:  `element.getTransformToElement(...)`