# How to get points from a D3 SVG bezier curve with given step size?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

So I have a D3 SVG bezier curve [like this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-line) :
[image]

I want to get X, Y coordinates of points with given step from the D3 path like so:

[image]

So to get an array of coordinate pairs with equal steps. If possible not recalculating bezier curve. How to do such a thing in D3js?

Comment: You can use the [getPointAtLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005065/get-point-coordination-using-path-getpointatlength-after-rotation-in-d3-and-svg) method

Comment: and set the ``pathLength`` attribute to easily get the steps you want without doing calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a bisection function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17896375/2103539) you probably want something like this:

```js
const
  svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = 512,
  height = 200;
const data = [];
const curve = "curveBasis";

var walk = function() {
  for (let i = 0, v = 2; i < 50; ++i) {
    v += Math.random() - 0.5;
    v = Math.max(Math.min(v, 4), 0);
    data.push({step: i, value: v});
  }
}

walk();

walkX = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 49])
  .range([10, width - 10]);

walkY = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 4])
  .range([200 - 10, 10]);

const line = d3.line()
  .curve(d3[curve])
  .x(d => walkX(d.step))
  .y(d => walkY(d.value));

svg
  .append("path")
  .attr("id", "svgpath")
  .attr("d", line(data))
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black");

var svgpath = document.getElementById("svgpath");

var findYatXbyBisection = function(x, path, error){
  var length_end = path.getTotalLength(),
  length_start = 0,
  point = path.getPointAtLength((length_end + length_start) / 2), // get the middle point
  bisection_iterations_max = 50,
  bisection_iterations = 0;

  error = error || 0.01;

  while (x < point.x - error || x > point.x + error) {
    // get the middle point
    point = path.getPointAtLength((length_end + length_start) / 2);

    if (x < point.x) {
      length_end = (length_start + length_end)/2;
    } else {
      length_start = (length_start + length_end)/2;
    }

  // Increase iteration
  if (bisection_iterations_max < ++ bisection_iterations)
    break;
  }
  return point.y
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  console.log(findYatXbyBisection(walkX(i), svgpath, 0.01).toFixed(4));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>SVG Line</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.1.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-COTaPOlz12cG4fSfcBsxZsjauBAyldqp+8FQUM/dZHm+ts/jR4AFoJhCqxy8K10Jrf3pojfsbq7fAPTb1XaVkg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
<svg id="chart" width="512" height="200">
</svg>
```

Do note that Y values returned are SVG coordinates so they start at 0 from the top of page. Check the range function used in the walkY function to refresh how you have to reverse the values for typical line and bar charts in D3.js.

And of course instead of logging to the console you can push the values to your custom array and use different interval value e.g. 1/n of the total line (path) width instead of 1/50 I've used (for 50 data points).